# How to create eloquent relationship for this query?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I had a query in laravel which producing 1128 data lists:

```
 $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                     ->join('sections', 'itemregistrations.sectionid', '=', 'sections.sectionid')
                     ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=', 'categories.categoryid')
                     ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
                     ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'sections.sectionname', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname')
                     ->get();
```

However, this query loads takes longer time...so is using eloquent relationship will help to speed the loading time? How to connect them using relationship?

1 itemregistration can be in 1 section, and one section can be registered by many itemregistration. is this one to many relationship?

The relation I created for section is:

```
  class Section extends Authenticatable
{
protected $table = 'sections';
protected  $primaryKey = 'SectionID';
 /**
 * Get the user that have agama.
 */
public function itemregistration()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itemregistration', 'ItemRegistrationID', 'SectionID');
}

}
```

Itemregistration model:

```
 class Itemregistration extends Model 
{
protected  $primaryKey = 'ItemRegistrationID';
protected $fillable = ['Name', 'Contact_Number','Address','NoOfCans','Price'];
public $timestamps = false;


public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section', 'ItemRegistrationID','SectionID');

}
}
```

But I cannot retrieve any value and got error when:

```
 $itemregistration = App\Section::find(1)->itemregistration;
```

Comment: Could really do with seeing the migration files that go along with this or a diagram of how everything is supposed to link together. I assume you've read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I had read many times but still confusing